# Don't reload an already loaded page with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, load

I have a menu and I want to load content in my div with ajax

If the page was loaded and i switch back to it the page must not be reloaded

My code is

```
$(".menulist").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

is there any solution 
thanks

Comment: detect what is currently loaded and stop if that's the case. simple.

Comment: So are you saying you want to cache the data returned and if you have gotten it before, don't retrieve it again, and simply set the html() with it?

Comment: @Taplar exactly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var requestCache = {};

$(".menulist").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    if ( requestCache[ url ] ) {
        $('#result').html(requestCache[url]);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                requestCache[url] = data;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: cant switch back to the loaded page if I use one

Comment: It will not perform the ajax request if requestCache has a key of whatever url is in it with a value.  Yes it will put the data in the html().  I thought this was the desired result?

Comment: yes it work it my mistak I forgot to do something thanks